# Разумность построения страниц GET запросами

Tags: php, html

я давно создаю сайты и вот с недавних пор я наткнулся на сайт который целиком и полностью был сделан на GET запросах, например:

```
example.com/?str=1&product=1&list=23 и даже настройки отображения там же
```

И я задался вопросом насколько это целесообразно и безопасно ?
Так я и приучился к этому и начал делать сайты таким образом, мне очень понравился данный метод тем, что не нужно парится кэшировать страницы, где-то хранить проверять потом подгружать и редиректить человека, загрузка теперь идет с большей скоростью т.к. все эти лишние действия убраны, поисковики как индексировали так и индексируют, закрывать страницы от пользователей стало проще и куча других плюсов, но раз так не все делают, то почему ?
Плюс ко всему прочему я еще и использую AJAX запросы которые так же берут данные с GET запроса;

Comment: пардоньте мое невежество, но какой у вас альтернативный способ создания сайтов без использования гет-запросов?

Comment: На генерации страниц, например example.com/index.php переход в папку example.com/products/pr1/index.php и так далее методом создания отдельного файла на каждую страницу

Comment: Это принцип работы http...сайты отличаются типом запросов...но запросы всегда одни и те же...`GET,POST,PUT,DELETE и т. д.` Когда вы пытаетесь получить `index.php` - это `get` запрос, который в `response` отдает `html`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц  таки  вопрос не про запросы, а про массовую передачу get-параметров

Comment: Нет, суть данного метода в том что каждая новая страница подгружается на главную example.com/index.php в него уже в зависимости GET запроса подгружается нужная страница

Comment: Не путаете ли вы GET-запрос как таковой и GET-параметры для него, из-за чего у вас сложилось впечатление, что ЧПУ ссылки не используют GET-запросы?

Comment: Скажем так. Я такое построение логики видел не раз. Да и сам так делал. Но ЧПУ намного лучше, имхо. Не зря фреймворки по умолчанию могут в ЧПУ. И вообще, маршруты — наше всё. :)

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего, нужно разобраться с основной разницей между запросом GET и запросом POST.

**GET-запросы** выполняются для запроса определенного ресурса с сервера. Любая информация, необходимая для извлечения нужного ресурса, передается в качестве параметров строки запроса.

**POST-запросы** делаются для публикации некоторых данных на конкретном ресурсе.

Мы не должны использовать GET запросы для отправки данных на сервер, их следует использовать только, как следует из названия, для получения определенного ресурса с сервера. Существует тонкая, но очень четкая грань между логическим использованием обоих.

Очень длинные URL не рекомендуются вообще. Чтобы веб-приложение было совместимо с различными браузерами, метод Get не должен использоваться для передачи очень длинных строк, содержащих более 2000 символов. Если вы столкнулись с ситуацией, когда вам нужно использовать URL-адреса, содержащие большое количество символов, подумайте еще раз.

Comment: имхо, это вряд ли хоть как-либо отвечает на вопрос автора. единственное, что он может отсюда вынести, что в гет не передать очень длинную строку

Comment: "сайт который целиком и полностью был сделан на GET запросах"... я скорее к тому, что строить архитектуру приложения исключительно на GET-запросах неверно. GET работает только на чтение и если предполагается использовать его повсеместно, он не должен модифицировать данные

Answer (score 0):

> example.com/products/pr1/index.php и так далее методом создания отдельного файла на каждую страницу

Вы серьезно? 
Хотя если это визитка из двух страниц.. то может и можно..

> насколько это целесообразно и безопасно ?

Смотря что вы имеете в виду под безопасностью.. 
https://mydomain.loc/login?user=user_name&pass=qwerty - как-бы.. не очень хорошо.

целесообразно ли?
Хотел бы посмотреть как вы отправляете файл 1мб GET-ом =))

> загрузка теперь идет с большей скоростью т.к. все эти лишние действия убраны

Как же у вас пост обрабатывается если дает просадку в производительности?
Или это один редирект так грузит?

> и даже настройки отображения там же

А что же в этом хорошего?

Молотком шуруп тоже можно забить и результат будет достигнут, так и тут.
Сайт можно сделать на чистом html, не используя БД, ЯП и т.д. - будет вообще летать как у Илона Маска. Но целесообразность этого зависит от Ваших целей.

Comment: `Вы серьезно? Хотя если это визитка из двух страниц` - вы не видели Битрикс :)

Comment: @TotalPusher была первая и единственная ЦМС в моем опыте. Это было лет 8 назад) До сих пор индексные файлы на уровне php инклюдят "хедеры"?)))))))

Comment: Я скажу что все так делали когда учились))

Просто автор написал: 

"я давно создаю сайты и вот с недавних пор"...

Comment: Дорогой писатель данного поста, сут не в том чтобы не использовать POST, а использовать только GET запросы для вывода страниц пользователю, приведу простой пример чтобы вам было понятно
`example.com/?str=1?delete_button_on=1?page=32`
Из этого следует, что человеку загрузится страница под номером 1, включатся на странице кнопки удаления(не нужно тут ворчать что это не безопасно они и на сессии проверяются по уровню доступа пользователей) и таблица будет на 38 странице. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: Например почти во всех cms и даже microsoft используют эту систему но редиректят на основную, например:
`example.com/?str=23124` на `example.com/pages/23124`

Comment: Тогда я не правильно прочитал ваш вопрос.. "наткнулся на сайт который целиком и полностью был сделан на GET запросах.." и "И я задался вопросом насколько это целесообразно...".

Исходя из этого и понял что вопрос в том чтобы вообще не использовать POST. Вы разъяснили